# Image transformation fails

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawimage

I have issue displaying a transformed image.
While the below code works correctly :

```
Image img = Resources.Resources.router;
PointF imageLocation = new PointF(10, 10);
g.DrawImage(img, imageLocation);
```

amending the above with a transformation throws exception "Parameter is invalid" at g.DrawImage() :

```
Image img = Resources.Resources.router;
PointF imageLocation = new PointF(10, 10);
img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipXY);
g.DrawImage(img, imageLocation);
```

I understand this type of error is related to some disposed object, but I can't figure out what is disposed here and when. The Image seems to be perfectly valid before calling g.DrawImage():
[image]

but then the below happens:
[image]

So what am I missing here, can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, although still not entirely sure about the reasons behind:

```
using (Image img = new Bitmap(Resources.Resources.router))
{
   PointF imageLocation = new PointF(10, 10);
   img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipXY);
   g.DrawImage(img, imageLocation);
}
```

Comment: In your screen capture your img was defined inside {} so it is local and would be randomly dumped on the close brace. I can only think that somegthing caused it to be disposed before it was handed on to GDI. The example with using may behave better because using defines a block that ultimately will try to dispose of img explicitly, so the library may behave better in this instance.

Comment: Thank you for explaining